# checking records in a table in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am checking if the records of a certain student in `tblborrowedbooks` exceeds the limit of 3 but my code doesnt seem to work.

I test this code to see if it works but it doesnt seem to work or it does work the opposite.

```
con.Open()
    Dim rs As New OdbcCommand("Select * from tblborrowedbooks where TagID = '" & lblTagID.Text & "'", con)
    rea = rs.ExecuteReader

    If rea.HasRows > 4 Then
        MsgBox("greater than 4")

    ElseIf rea.HasRows < 4 Then
        MsgBox("less than 4")
con.close
```

when there is 2 records with that tagid, msgbox pops up with less than 4 which is correct, but when i add 3 more records with that tagid which makes up for 5 records, it still shows the messagebox less than 4.

Comment: As explained in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.hasrows(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) `HasRows` returns a Boolean, so comparing `True` or `False` to 3 or 4 is nonsensical.  And do not concat strings to make queries.

Comment: Don't use concatenation - use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters) instead.

Comment: What is the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what database you are using. I used SQL Server in my example. Adjust for your provider. Since all you need from the database is a count, don't pull down extra data, just get the Count. I have guessed at data types for the `Parameters.Add()` Using parameters helps protect against SQL injection. `.ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row, no need for a reader. The `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your objects are closed and disposed of properly even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim strSQL = "Select Count(*) From tblborrowedbooks where TagID = @TagID;"
        Using con As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TagID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = lblTagID.Text
                con.Open()
                result = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End Using
        If result > 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("At least 3 books are already checked out.")
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using Xampp mysql. Thanks this code works. I'll try to use parameters  always Thank you.

Comment: Jay, if this code solved your problem, please mark the answer as the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Glad it works for you. I think you will find parameters fairly easy, once you get used to them.